# removeEventListeners doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to make a simple script to handle rating using the star system. 
I stopped at the moment of pressing on the star, because all stars should stay in position after clicking on one while event listener is being removed only for this one.

Can you tell what am I doing wrong? I doubt removeEventListener doesn't work properly ;|

```js
const drawStars = (node, starsNumber = 5, cssRef = "_star") => {
  if (starsNumber < 1)
    return false;

  let star;

  // classes to aply when star's filled or not
  const starFilled = `fas fa-star ${cssRef}`;
  const starContour = `far fa-star ${cssRef}`;

  // drawing stars
  for (let i = 1; i <= starsNumber; i++) {
    star = document.createElement('i');
    star.className = `${starContour} ${cssRef}`;
    node.appendChild(star);
  }

  node = [...node.childNodes];

  // putting listeners on every star
  node.forEach((star, index) => {

    // filling stars after hovering
    const mouseOverStar = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < starsNumber; i++) {
        if (i <= index)
          node[i].className = starFilled;
        else
          node[i].className = starContour;
      }
    }

    // cleaning stars when mouse is out and no star was clicked
    const mouseOutStar = () => {
      node.forEach(star => star.className = starContour);
    }

    // trying to remove event listeners from every star but with no effect
    const clickOnStar = () => {
      node.forEach(star => {
        star.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutStar);
        star.removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverStar);
      })
    }

    // applying listeners
    star.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverStar);
    star.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutStar);
    star.addEventListener('click', clickOnStar);
  });
}


// example of use
const starsContainer = document.querySelector('.stars');
drawStars(starsContainer);
```

```css
.stars {
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(231, 199, 19);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="stars"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are defining your listener functions inside an event handler, making them only accessible within their local scope. This means every time that listener is run, you are creating a new listener, regardless of it being a `const`.

see: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your event handlers `mouseOverStar`, `mouseOutStar` and `clickOnStar` outside the `drawStars` function.

You need to reference the exact same handler both in `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` for it to work.

Check https://www.jonportella.com/you-are-using-browser-events-wrong/